# I get "t.openWindow is not a function" errors when I use TestCafe Window Management methods

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

The process for writing multiple windows tests described in TestCafe documentation seems pretty straightforward:
`await t.openWindow('https://url.com/addnewproperty')`
or even
`const initialWindow = await t.getCurrentWindow()`

should do it. However, every time I use any of the Window Management methods I get the errors:

`TypeError: t.openWindow is not a function` and cannot do anything about it.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong and how to solve the issue?

TestCafe version 1.9.4

Comment: Is `t` the test controller? Can you share the whole test case or even file?

Comment: yes, it is. the code looks like this:

`test('Multiple tabs', async t => {
  await loginPage.login(loginInfo);
  await t.setNativeDialogHandler(() => true);

  // Open new window
  await t.openWindow(baseUrl);
  await t.expect(appBar.appBarContainer.visible).ok();

  // Log out in new window
  await appBar.clickIcon();
  await t.click(appBar.logout);
  await t.expect(loginPage.emailInput.visible).ok();`

As you can see, `async t` is there, and the only thing that does not work with `t` is `openWindow`. Things like expect, click or any other methods work just fine.

Comment: The code looks correct. The cause of the issue can be in the fact that you probably globally installed TestCafe and locally installed TestCafe, and it's possible that these versions differ. Please specify the command you use to run your tests. Please also check the TestCafe version with the following commands: `testcafe -v`, `npx testcafe -v`, `node node_modules/testcafe/bin/testcafe -v`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in different versions of Test Cafe used between main codebase and one of the underlying packages. Alex Kamaev answer was a correct one

Comment: Please don't answer confirming the correctness of someone else's answer. Once you have enough reputation leave this as a comment instead.